# Django-tables2: Change text displayed in column title

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am working with a MySQL view (Create View as Select ...) and have successfully manged to connect the view to a model like this:

```
#models.py
class Dashboard(models.Model):
    devenv = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    numberofissues = models.BigIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table = 'stability_dashboard'
```

I have also managed to display data in a table using the boiler plate code from the example:

```
#tables.py
class DashboardTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Dashboard
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}

#views.py
def dashboard(request):
    table = DashboardTable(Dashboard.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'uptime/dash.html', {'table': table})
```

I would now like to change the title displayed in each column to something more understandable including spaces e.g. Instead of 'devenv' => 'Development Environment'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just add the columns whose names you want to override in your tables.py. For instance

```
#tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables
from models import Dashboard

class DashboardTable(tables.Table):
  devenv = tables.Column(verbose_name= 'Development Environment' )

  class Meta:
    model = Dashboard
    attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

Another (probably more DRY) solution is to leave tables.py as is and add verbose_name in your model definition:

```
#models.py
class Dashboard(models.Model):
    devenv = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True, verbose_name='Development Environment')
    numberofissues = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Number of Issues')
    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table = 'stability_dashboard'
```