# django-tables2 not displaying column headers

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm generating a leaderboard using [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) based on this model (in `users/models.py`):

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    points = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=20, 
        decimal_places=2,
        default=Decimal('1000.00'))
```

In `tables.py`, I select `username` and `points`, and order by the latter:

```
class UserTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username','points')
        order_by = '-points'
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

In `views.py`, I have

```
def leaderboard_list(request):
    table = UserTable(CustomUser.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

    return render(request, 'leaderboard.html', {
        'table': table
    })
```

Finally, this gets rendered in the `leaderboard.html` template with `{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}` and `{% render_table table %}`.

**The table renders fine, but without any column headers.**

**Attempt 1**:
I added a `verbose_name` to the `points` field of the `CustomUser` model in light of [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601300/django-tables2-change-text-displayed-in-column-title), under the assumption that this should show by default (as per [this](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-headers-and-footers.html)), but to no avail.

**Attempt 2**:
The following gives me the column names, but only when I set `orderable=False`, which means I can no longer order by `points`:

```
class UserTable(tables.Table):
    username = tables.Column(verbose_name='User name', orderable=False, accessor=Accessor('username'))
    points = tables.Column(verbose_name='Points', orderable=False, accessor=Accessor('points'))
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username','points')
        order_by = '-points'
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes to have this issue, here's one solution:

First, set `orderable=False` on each column in the table class, to ensure that all the headers are showing:

```
class UserTable(tables.Table):
    username = tables.Column(verbose_name='Username', orderable=False, accessor=Accessor('username'))
    points = tables.Column(verbose_name='Points', orderable=False, accessor=Accessor('points'))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username','points')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

Then, add a `Meta` as follows on the `CustomUser` model, as follows, to have the table order by points:

```
class Meta:
        ordering = ['-points']
```